# How to access the controls on a UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, user-controls

I've created two UserControls (named UserControl1 and UserControl2) and dynamically add one to a panel:

```
UserControl yoozerControl;
if (pi != pie) {
    yoozerControl = new UserControl1();
} else {
    yoozerControl = new UserControl2();
}
panel1.Controls.Add(yoozerControl);
yoozerControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

However, I cannot access the UserControls' members. e.g., UserControl1 has a TextBox1, but this won't compile:

```
UserControl yoozerControl;
if (pi != pie) {
    yoozerControl = new UserControl1();
    String s = yoozerControl.TextBox1.Text;
. . .
```

What must I do to access the properties of the controls on the UserControls?

### UPDATE

```
// I was able to successfully test this by changing UserControl1's TextBox1 Modifier
// property to public, and the same with UserControl2's label1 Modifier property.
UserControl1 yoozerControl = null;
UserControl2 yowzerControl = null;
String s = String.Empty;
if (AppType.Equals(SearchTypes.Platypus)) {
    yoozerControl = new UserControl1();
    s = yoozerControl.textBox1.Text;
} else {
    yowzerControl = new UserControl2();
    s = yowzerControl.label1.Text;
}
    if (!(null == yoozerControl)) {
    panel1.Controls.Add(yoozerControl);
    yoozerControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
if (!(null == yowzerControl)) {
    panel1.Controls.Add(yowzerControl);
    yowzerControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the user control to be typed as Your control.  UserControl1 or UserControl2 (not UserControl)

And as Adam mentioned, if you haven't already made things publicly accessible, you'll need to deal with that as well.

Answer (score 3):

After you appropriately type yoozerControl, as @Kenneth said (+1 to him), you'll need to expose those textboxes as public properties of your user control:

```
public TextBox yourTB{
    get { return TextBox1; }
}
```

Or, to be a bit cleaner, just expose a property that returns the textbox's **text**, which is what you seem to need.

```
public string yourTBsText {
    get { return TextBox1.Text; }
}
```

Comment: The proper way to expose a control is to set the "Modifiers" property to whatever visibility you desire.

Comment: @w.brian - assuming you really want the whole textbox exposed, sure.  Depending on his situation, exposing the TB's text through a plain C# property may be the ideal solution.

Comment: I 'm just trying to supply the most ideal solution to the question as it was asked.  Doing it manually when there is designer support for exposing controls isn't ideal, at least with his stated requirements.

Comment: Unless there's some sort of compelling reason to expose the textbox directly, it's usually better to create your own property.  Making the textbox public is the same thing as having a public field.  Breaks encapsulation / increasing coupling.

Comment: `Increases coupling` - exactly - that was my main concern.  @Ken

Comment: True enough.  Like I said, I try to answer questions as they're asked, not necessarily tell people they should be doing it differently.

Answer (score 2):

On your user control, select the control that you want to expose and look at the properties window.  Change the "Modifiers" property to "Public" to give it the most visibility.

Comment: +1 - if the user really just wants the whole TB exposed, then this is the right answer (once you do what Kenneth said)